# Immutable.js Set contains duplicate values

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I'm facing an issue with Immutable.js' Set, which according to the docs can only contains unique values. 
The code in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sylvaingirard/8qv7u3yw/2/) will result in 2 duplicate entries in the set.

Although this unit test passes, the issue is most likely user error.

```
it('should only have unique object values', () => {
  const set = Set<any>();
  const newSet = set.add({ form: 'form1', name: 'control1', value: 10 });
  const finalSet = set.add({ form: 'form1', name: 'control1', value: 10 });
  expect(finalSet.count()).toBe(1);
});
```

Anyone able to explain this?

Comment: Note that you have a typo in your test case - you're adding to `set` both times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in your test case - you're adding to `set` both times (rather than to `newSet` the second time).  If you fix this, then the test fails.

[Immutable.js's `Set` uses `Immutable.is` to check for equality](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Set).  But that doesn't behave as you expect - it doesn't consider distinct JS objects (even with the same structure) to be equal:

```
const x = { a: 1 };
const y = { a: 1 };
console.log(Immutable.is(x, y));                                       // false
```

This is fixed by switching to immutable objects:<sup>1</sup>

```
console.log(Immutable.is(Immutable.fromJS(x), Immutable.fromJS(y)));   // true
```

---

<sub>1. which you should generally do as early as possible, in order to avoid these kinds of subtle issues.</sub>

Comment: Ok, now I feel stupid... And by coincidence, you answered what would have been my followup question: how to make sure only one of them makes it in :)

Answer (score 2):

I've done:

```
    const stuff = Immutable.List(data)
        .map(x => Immutable.fromJS(x))
        .toSet()
        .map(x => x.toJS())
```

My input is an array of objects, and make all the objects immutable, then the set doesn't any longer contain incomplete values.

Not that this is a better answer, in fact I realised it's what I needed to do after reading this. It's not a bad pattern though.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the two objects you add are actually different objects (and therefore different values in the set) even though they contain the same key/value pairs.

the other issue is that you do not use newSet to create finalSet.

if you use the actual same object twice it will work:

```
it('should only have unique object values', () => {
  const set = Set<any>();
  const obj = { form: 'form1', name: 'control1', value: 10 };
  const newSet = set.add(obj);
  const finalSet = newSet.add(obj);
  expect(finalSet.count()).toBe(1);
});
```

Comment: I think the OP is expecting them the two objects to be equivalent, and thus to satisfy `Immutable.is` (see https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Set).

Comment: Correct, and if you read closely, I'm stating that the test actually passes but the code in the fiddle doesn't behave in the same way.

Comment: well this code works, and the other subtle change is that have not used newSet to create the finalSet. This is probably your issue. I certainly don't think this answer deserved a downvote